# Allow only numeric and float values with validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a field `days` in my model, now I want to only save `integer` or `float` values in this column.

Values can be like:

- `1`
- `2`
- `0.5`
- `2.5`

I tried to use `numeric` but then it is not allowing me to input `float` values:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'days' => 'required|numeric|min:1|max:50',
]);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Pradeep : i tried your solution but ity is not allowing me to enter values like : 0.5

Comment: just remove the `min:1`

Comment: @Pradeep: shouldd i use only `required|digits` bacause currently i'm using `required|digits_between:0,100`

Comment: try with this  `'required|numeric|min:0|max:50'`

Comment: @Pradeep I tried this but it is not working

Comment: it should work with `numeric` with float or int what is error u get

Comment: @Pradeep: when i enter numbers like 1 or 2 it is working but it is not alllowing me float values like 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try custom validation rules for your case.
Example:

```
'days' => 'required|regex:/^\d*(\.\d{2})?$/'
```

Comment: I would not recommend using a `regex` for such a simple thing, it is overkill for someone that could not know regex at all compared to my answer. Also, it is less performant (even though this is a simple number to check).

Answer (score 1):

You can use closures if no [validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#available-validation-rules) helps you.

So, first try this:

```php
'days' => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:50',
```

If it is not working, we can use [closures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-closures):

```php
'days' => [
    'required',
    'numeric',
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if ($value <= 0) {
            $fail($attribute.' must be greater than 0.');
        }
    },
    'max:50',
],
```

Have in mind that [`numeric`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/160c7199fb3d7efa1b5f6c818496d51e70e9cbbe/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1367-L1370) validation, uses [`is_numeric`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) built-in PHP function.